# spyOn static method - Jasmine ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a class that creates a new instance that contains a static method thats called within the same class. I wish to spy on that method to make sure it's being called from the other class method on the jasmine test.

A.js

```
class A {
    methodA() {
        let check = A.methodB(); // ping
    }
    static methodB() {
        return 'ping'
    }
}

export default new A();
```

A.spec.js

```
import A from './A.js'    

it('...', () => {
   spyOn(A, 'methodB'); // Error: <spyOn> : methodB() method does not exist
});
```

Comment: This seems to work when i call spyOn(A.constructor, 'methodB') . Is this the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this issue is the following:

```
spyOn(A.constructor, 'methodB')
```